# Sql query to print all the rows if row value changes from previous

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like

```
 id device_id  time   mode   sign        plan  
  1   1001     9.00     1      1          A
  2   1001     9.01     2      1          A
  3   1001     9.02     3      1          B
  4   1001     9.03     4      1          B
  5   1001     9.04     5      1          A
```

I want to writa an sql query that prints all the rows if plan value changes from previous row. so that the output should be

```
 1   1001     9.00     1      1          A
 3   1001     9.02     3      1          B
 5   1001     9.04     5      1          A
```

Is there any way to do this? This is large table with lot of other columns and >100k of data. 
Joining with the same table doesn't work as it takes too long to execute.

I tried with this.

```
SELECT device_id, time ,  mode ,  sign  ,plan
FROM table where id IN
(SELECT MIN(id) FROM table GROUP BY plan)
```

But this gives only

```
 1   1001     9.00     1      1          A
 3   1001     9.02     3      1          B
```

Can anyone suggest any improved version of this query which gives

```
 1   1001     9.00     1      1          A
 3   1001     9.02     3      1          B
 5   1001     9.04     5      1          A
```

Comment: distinct on ... order by plan?..

Comment: can you make it a bit more clear? like a query?

Comment: I'he put it as an answer. If you provide your structure in DDL and some data sample, I can adjust the query to your sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`lag` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html):

```
select  *
from    (
        select  lag(plan) over (order by id desc) as prev_plan
        ,       *
        from    YourTable
        ) yt
where   plan <> prev_plan
        or prev_plan is null
```

[Example at regtester.](http://rextester.com/WLGLPZ98537)

Comment: this looks fine. But i dont want an extra column like "prev_plan".

Comment: You can omit the new column from the result by replacing the outer `*` with the columns you want.  Like `select col1, col2, col3 from (....`

Comment: it takes around 15 minutes to execute.As I said table is very large.